# Active task = active story. Yes/ No?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a project in VSTS. The project consists of a few features, stories and tasks as shown:

```
F1
--F1S1
----F1S1T1
----F1S1T2
```

Lets assume all the above mentioned items are present in `Iteration 1`. Now if I move the task `F1S1T1` from `new` to `active`, shouldn't the story be moved to active in the `Stories` board and the feature be moved to active in the `Features` board?

Write now if a task is active, I have to go and specifically move the story to active and then move the feature to active, so that colleagues can find that the feature is currently undergoing development.

Is there a workaround to move the feature and story to active automatically? Or am I making use of VSTS the right way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, **User story state has not direct relations with task state**. You can find the  work flow for User story and task [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/agile-process-workflow#agile-workflow-states).

- When set user story state as Active: when you started to work on this item (implementation started). And usually after the user story is Active, then you can add tasks for this user story. And task states can be any of the state (New, Active, Close or Removed) since a user story usually  contains more than one task.
- When set task state as Active: when you started on this task (work started).

So for your situation, when you started on the user story `F1S1`, you should change the state as Active. When you start to work on the task `F1S1T1`, you should change the task state as Active. And before you started on the task `F1S1T1`, the user story `F1S1` state should be changed to Active already.

Comment: Why would you want to enable a scenario, where a user story is in state New when one or more of its tasks are in state Active? Or same for a feature in regard to user stories. Often times the whole tree is created in advance with some, if not all tasks, before any work starts. Then that user story is scheduled, work on a task begins and I would assume it would make many peoples lives easier if the parent levels were moved to active state with it.

Comment: Agree with Tuukka here. At least the way we work, there are no possibillities for a user story to be in "New" when one of its task is "Active". Similarly, when all of a user stories tasks are closed, the user story can have no other states other than Resolved.

Answer (score 6):

This question is still relevant for Microsoft Azure DevOps (the cloud service).
You start working on a task, so you mark it active, however the parent story / feature / epic is still in new state.

I'd consider it a defect.

Comment: This capability can be upvoted at the community feedback page [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/515532/parent-active-while-sub-task-move-to-active.html).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no way to do this in Azure DevOps - even though this seems like a no brainer.

This feature was requested at least once that I know of back in Apr 03, 2019
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/parent-active-while-sub-task-move-to-active/515532

The default behavior should be:

When a Bug or Task is changed to Active, then it’s parent User Story should automatically change to Active. If a User Story is changed to Active then its parent Feature should change to Active.

When all Tasks/bugs are closed, then the user story should automatically close. When all user stories are closed then the Feature should automatically close.

This seems very obvious and should be a simple workflow to implement. Other systems such as Jira (although it requires a plugin) support this.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-move-DONE-stories-to-DONE-column-in-Active-Sprint-board/qaq-p/787431

If there are cases/scenarios where this behavior may not apply for one reason or another, then making this a configurable setting that you can either turn on or off would be a good option.

p.s. I upvoted the feature request

Answer (score 0):

With the newest version, this should be possible now:

I can't confirm it yet as I'm unsure whether the blocker I do currently observe is based on DevOps itself or my user authorization settings given by my company.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops